# Simple C++ dashboard library?

Tags: linux, c++, monitoring, dashboard

Is there any free library that allows me to effortlessly monitor metrics on my C++ application?

Something that would allow me to visualize e.g. *transactions per second* or *runtime overhead* in a 2D plot (the same way most monitoring tools plot e.g. CPU usage).

Similar to [Graphite](https://graphiteapp.org) or [Riemann](http://riemann.io) but in a simple self-contained way. My dream would be something like:

```
// effortlessly create a dashboard object
Dashboard &d = DashboardBuilder();
// configure it to my liking
d.addMetric("CPU%", PLOT_OVER_TIME);
// show it in terminal, or web interface... as long as I can specify in a high-level
d.webInterface(8080);
// emit the events I need
d.emit("CPU%", getCPUPercentage());
```

Comment: welcome aboard. I hope that you get an answer to his, as it is very interesting question. Personally, I prefer my output as plain ascii text, so that I can manipulate it, although a GUJI over that would be great. What about number of threads at any given time, time spent in each thread, stack size ... ?

Comment: Asking for *simple* library and then jumping into requiring it to have embedded web server?

Comment: Or some other user-friendly zero-configuration way of visualizing the data. Simple for the user :-) Ideally supporting many front-ends (webpage, CLI…)

Comment: Can you please share whether you found a library for your need? It is also a very interesting topic for me.

Comment: @ZhengQu I did not :( sorry.